# Stripe API not working in edit mode Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

For a wordpress website I'm using the checkout API from Stripe to handle payments. It works all fine on the front-end. The site redirects to the checkout page of Stripe but when I want to edit the content in the admin panel of Wordpress, it is not working and giving the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Stripe\Stripe'
```

In my page.643 I'm including the Stripe library

```
<?php require_once('stripe-php/init.php');?>
```

It looks like this init.php file is only added to the front-end of the website. How could I change this that it will work on the admin part of the site as well?

Comment: Hi solidesuus, how did you install the Stripe bindings? From your require statement it looks like you went with the manual installation and copied stripe-php's latest release into root of your project - is that correct? Also, stripe-php is a server-side library, and will not work on the frontend. For that you need Stripe.js. Lastly, I should mention that the most common way to integrate with Stripe+Wordpress is through a plugin, have you given that a shot? https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/stripe.